# image file uploaded to WebApi cannot be decoded to a bitmap in SkiaSharp

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, skiasharp

**I have this method that adds a watermark to an image using SkiaSharp:**

```
    public static class Watermarker
    {
        public static string AddWatermark(string imgPath, string text, string outputPath)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(imgPath)) throw new FileNotFoundException();
            SKBitmap bitmap = null;
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(imgPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(file);
            }

            using (SKPaint textPaint = new SKPaint {
                TextSize = bitmap.Width / 30,
                Typeface = SKTypeface.FromFamilyName("Arial", SKFontStyle.Bold),
                ColorF = SKColorF.FromHsl(0,0,40),
                BlendMode = SKBlendMode.Modulate
            })
            using (SKSurface surface = SKSurface.Create(new SKImageInfo(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height)))
            using (SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas)
            {
                canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, new SKPoint(0,0));
                canvas.DrawText(text, (bitmap.Width / 2) - (textPaint.MeasureText(text) / 2), bitmap.Height / 2, textPaint);

                using (var image = surface.Snapshot())
                using (var data = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg, 80))
                using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(outputPath))
                data.SaveTo(stream);
            }

            return outputPath;
        }
    }
```

It works fine with an exsisting image file from the disk.

However when using this method with a file uploaded from a WebApi that is saved temporarily on the disk, the method fails when trying to decode the image into a bitmap, creating the FileStream works just fine.

**Here's the WebApi Controller:**

```
public class WatermarkController : UmbracoApiController
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
        public WatermarkController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _env = env;
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddWatermarkToImage(IFormFile file, string text)
        {
            using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "upload", $"test.jpg"), FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
            var uploadPath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "upload", "tmp", $"test.jpg");
            var finishedPath = Watermarker.AddWatermark(uploadPath, "Muster", Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "upload", $"test.jpg"));

            var finishedStream = System.IO.File.Create(finishedPath);
            return File(finishedStream, "image/jpeg");
        }
    }
```

**And here's the error it produces:**

````
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'buffer')
   at SkiaSharp.SKManagedStream.OnReadManagedStream(IntPtr buffer, IntPtr size)
   at SkiaSharp.SKAbstractManagedStream.ReadInternal(IntPtr s, Void* context, Void* buffer, IntPtr size)
   at SkiaSharp.SkiaApi.sk_codec_new_from_stream(IntPtr stream, SKCodecResult* result)
   at SkiaSharp.SKCodec.Create(SKStream stream, SKCodecResult& result)
   at SkiaSharp.SKBitmap.Decode(Stream stream)
   at Watermark.Watermarker.AddWatermark(String imgPath, String text, String outputPath) in C:\Users\Herrmann AG\source\repos\Watermark\Watermark\Watermarker.cs:line 16
   at Umbraco10Test.Controllers.WatermarkController.AddWatermarkToImage(IFormFile file, String text)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Middleware.BasicAuthenticationMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<<UseMiddlewareInterface>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Umbraco.Cms.Web.BackOffice.Middleware.BackOfficeExternalLoginProviderErrorMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<<UseMiddlewareInterface>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at SixLabors.ImageSharp.Web.Middleware.ImageSharpMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, Boolean retry)
   at StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfilerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\projects\dotnet\src\MiniProfiler.AspNetCore\MiniProfilerMiddleware.cs:line 119
   at Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Middleware.UmbracoRequestMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
   at Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Middleware.UmbracoRequestMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<<UseMiddlewareInterface>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Middleware.PreviewAuthenticationMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<<UseMiddlewareInterface>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Middleware.UmbracoRequestLoggingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<<UseMiddlewareInterface>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```
````

Comment: For 'FileStream' you are using "Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "upload", $"test.jpg")", but for the "uploadPath" you are using "Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "upload", "tmp", $"test.jpg")". UploadPath has a additional "tmp" or do i miss something here?